# What happens when we calculate this-(object of current class)

Tags: c++, object, this

i have class name DPPoint what happens when we calculate this-(object of DPPoint) in same class and assign value to a variable of type int

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: It will depend on the implementation of overloaded `-` operator.

Comment: can you add your implementation of the operator? or some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the question is about this:

```
DPPoint* p1 = new DPPoint;
DPPoint* p2 = new DPPoint;
int k = p1 - p2; // what is k?
```

That's perfectly valid code. It's called "pointer arithmetic". It will give you distance between p1 and p2 in sizes of DPPoint.

```
DPPoint array [10];
int k = &array[5] - &array[3]; // k = 2
int n = (int)&array[5] - (int)&array[3]; // n = 2 * sizeof (DPPoint)
(&array[5] == &array[3] + 2); // true
(&array[5] == array + 5); // also true
```

The pointers don't have to be in the same array. Can be two random addresses in memory (skipping alignment issues for simplicity).

Comment: That first example is **not** "perfectly valid code". The pointers **must** be in the same array (or possible one after). Your example exhibits Undefined Behavior.  The second part is OK.